# Visitors from strange IP addresses

Tags: linux, ip

Almost every day I have new users on my website that come from strange IP addresses:

```
162.158.102.39
162.158.102.41
162.158.103.42
etc.
```

[Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/) says these IP addresses belong to Poland, Cloudflare. But CloudFlare is a company that offers reverse proxy services. How is it possible that people come from these IP addresses?

At the same time [RIPE](https://apps.db.ripe.net/) reports that these IP addresses are not even European IP addresses.

These are not spiders, bots but real people. They create profiles, upload photos etc

So, does anyone know something about these IP addresses?

Comment: As long as the visitor is not from 66.6.66.6 ... you probably [don't need to worry](http://www.ipvoid.com/scan/162.158.103.42/)

Comment: Geolocation services are not perfect.

Comment: You have a publicly accessible website. I'm not sure what you expected, but I would have expected to see connections from any ip address... anywhere in the world.

Comment: Why do you think these connections are "strange"?

Comment: RIPE is right, MaxMind is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Every* server on the internet is constantly bombarded with requests from all kind of spiders and bots and as long as your system is secure and updated, there is usually no need to worry about it.

Comment: These are not spiders, bots but real people. They create profiles, upload photos etc.

Comment: Maybe spammers ... Anyway, it you can't filter them and maybe block them with stuff like Captchas, you have to live with it. There is no need to "know anything about these IP addresses".

Answer (score 0):

Just ask CloudFlare via [www.cloudflare.com](http://www.cloudflare.com)

They will know the answer.

And check [THIS](https://cleantalk.org/blacklists/162.158.103.42) out:

```
162.158.103.42 spam attacks log

Date/ time (GMT)    Email   Sender Nickname Anti-spam app
Dec 15, 2015 08:45:18   breannahargrove@bigstring.com   herpes simplex cure v2.33 WordPress 
Dec 05, 2015 23:36:17   nettiecp16@jimenajimena.lavaweb.in  marisakh60  v5.33 WordPress 
Dec 05, 2015 15:35:37   teri.dendy@yahoo.de rapidpharma.mediahostforph.com  v2.33 WordPress 
Dec 01, 2015 09:35:50   bryantvanover@gmx.de    www.rapidpharma.biz v2.33 WordPress 
Nov 29, 2015 12:54:24   premise@proven.am   bcbgmaxazria fringe dress red   v2.33 WordPress 
Nov 29, 2015 12:27:13   nipping@semicolon.bs    belstaff vancouver 2015 v2.33 WordPress 
Nov 29, 2015 12:49:12   seedling@bug.ms jaeger lecoultre reverso batman v2.33 WordPress
```

Those seem to be simply a spambots.